# PHP get the item in an array that has the most duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of strings and I am looking for a way to find the most common string in the array.

```
$stuff = array('orange','banana', 'apples','orange');
```

I would want to see orange.

Comment: <nitpick>`array( ... );`, not `{ ... }`</nitpick> :P

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
$c = array_count_values($stuff); 
$val = array_search(max($c), $c);
```

Comment: Delightful! Thank you very much

Answer (score 10):

Use `array_count_values` and get the key of the item:

```
<?php
$stuff = array('orange','banana', 'apples','orange', 'xxxxxxx');

$result = array_count_values($stuff);
asort($result);
end($result);
$answer = key($result);

echo $answer;
?>
```

Output:

```
orange
```

Comment: Nice, bear in mind due to unstable sort it's unpredictable if multiple elements have the same highest frequency in the array.

Comment: you can also do array_slice() after doing arsort() if you want the top 5 results for example