# Find the most frequent number in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP with repeating numbers and I would like to find the most frequent but only when there is only one of that.

```
while (count(array_count_values($arr)) > 1) {
$minim = min(array_count_values($arr));
while ($minim == min(array_count_values($arr))) {
    unset($arr[array_search(array_search(min(array_count_values($arr)), array_count_values($idList)), $arr)]);
    $arr = array_splice($arr, 0, 1);
}
}
```

In my code the first while runs until I have only one number (multiple times) in the array and with the second one I delete the less frequent numbers.
My problem is the I get this error for my **second** min(): "Array must contain at least one element".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the most repeated values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612126/getting-the-most-repeated-values-in-an-array)

Comment: This question is lacking a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an array in PHP with repeating numbers and I would like to find the most frequent but only when there is only one of that.

Your approach seems rather complicated.

Here's how I'd do that:

```
$numbers = [1, 6, 5, 6, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8]; // positive test case
//$numbers = [1, 6, 5, 6, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8, 1];  // negative test case

$count = array_count_values($numbers); // get count of occurrence for each number

arsort($count); // sort by occurrence, descending

$first = key($count); // get key of first element, because that is the/one
                      // of the highest number(s)
$count_first = current($count); // get occurrence for first array value
$count_second = next($count); // get occurrence for second array value

if($count_first != $count_second) { // did they occur in different frequencies?
  echo $first . ' occurred most in input array.';
}
else {
  echo 'input array contained multiple values with highest occurrence.';
}
```

Comment: lol i had no idea PHP had an `array_count_values` function... Oh PHP, the surprises just keep coming. I removed the `array_reduce` in my answer in favor of this built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably perform an `array_reduce` on the counts to find the max, but because `array_reduce` does not give you access to the iterable's *key*, you'd have to perform additional transformation.

Instead, I would recommend you build your own `MaxHeap` by extending from [`SplMaxHeap`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splmaxheap.php)

```
class MaxHeap extends SplMaxHeap {
  public function compare($a, $b) {
    if (current($a) < current($b))
      return -1;
    elseif (current($a) > current($b))
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Then we can use it as such – the answer says `[ 7 => 4 ]` which means: **7** is the most common number, appearing **4** times

```
$heap = new MaxHeap();
foreach (array_count_values($numbers) as $n => $count)
  $heap->insert([$n => $count]);

print_r($heap->top());
// [ 7 => 4 ]

printf("%d is the most common number, appearing %d times",
  key($heap->top()),
  current($heap->top())
);
// 7 is the most common number, appearing 4 times
```

---

**complete script**

```
$numbers = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9];

class MaxHeap extends SplMaxHeap {
  public function compare($a, $b) {
    if (current($a) < current($b))
      return -1;
    elseif (current($a) > current($b))
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
  }
}

$heap = new MaxHeap();
foreach (array_count_values($numbers) as $n => $count)
  $heap->insert([$n => $count]);

printf("%d is the most common number, appearing %d times",
  key($heap->top()),
  current($heap->top())
);
```

---

**revision history**

I was unaware of PHP's native [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function. I removed the more complex `array_reduce` in favor of this super specialised function. Thanks, @CBroe.

Comment: With this I don't know if there is multiple most frequent element. For example if I add one more 1 to the array, I get that 1 is the most frequent. I want to know if there is only one most frequent and only then the exact number.

Comment: @utinum and what exactly is the "problem" with that? if that's the case, then yes, it will return the *first* most frequent element in the heap. What would be a non-problematic answer? Should it return both? If there's a tie, should it return the larger number? If there's a tie, should it return `null` if because there is no *most* common number? My point is, it's not a *problem*, the behaviour is just *undefined*. *Define* what you'd like to happen and we can make it happen.